# C++ buzzer to play piano notes for an Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, arduino

```
unsigned long t;
boolean isHigh;

#define BUZZER_PIN 3

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  isHigh = false;
  t = micros();
}

void loop() {
  playNote('c');
}

void playNote(char note) {
  unsigned long timeToWait;
  unsigned long timeToPlayTheNote = millis();
  while (timeToPlayTheNote - millis() < 1000) {
    if (note == 'c') {
      timeToWait = 1911;
    }
    if (micros() - t > timeToWait) {
      if (!isHigh) {
        digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, HIGH);
        isHigh = true;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW);
        isHigh = false;
      }
      t = micros();
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why this won't work. I used to play a frequency every 1,000 microseconds but is there any way to make this simpler as well? Also, with this method I have to do (1/f)/2 and then convert that value from seconds to microseconds and use that as the value for timeToWait.

Comment: Code never calls `playNote` function in loop nor its registered as an `ISR`

Comment: It works now but is there anyway to make it more efficient as I would need a lot of else if statements for each note

Comment: Another way will be using `Timmer Interrupts` in place of waiting for time.

Comment: One more simplification can be replacing logic for toggling `BUZZER_PIN` with: `digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, isHigh);` `isHigh=!isHigh;`

Comment: Is my method inefficient?

Comment: It depends. This method keeps the control at `if` statement until specified time have elapsed. But if you want to do some other thing simultaneously, then using Interrupts are best.

Answer (score 0):

- Initialization of ˋtimeToWait` should obviously be outside of the loop.
- An array could be used for timing data.
- ˋt` should probably be initialized inside ˋplayNoteˋ
- Alternatively, you might use an enum for delay associated to a note.

  ```
  enum class notes
  {
      C = 1911
  };
  ```

Well, all suggestion assume that you don't want to compensate for drifting offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Buzzers have a fixed frequency.  They don't work like speakers at all.  You will get better results with a real speaker.  Don't forget to put a capacitor in series with it so the speaker sees an AC signal, you can fry a speaker quite easily if you feed it a DC signal..

For best results, you should use 2 x 47uF to 100uF electrolytic capacitors back to back, with the negative poles joined together, one positive to the 'duino and the other positive pole connected to the speaker.  With higher capacitance, you'll get more bass.

Why don't you use a PWM at 50% (128) and change the PWM frequency to generate the sound?  You could use the Timer1 or Timer3 library for that.  Letting the hardware do the work would be more presise and would free your application for other tasks, such as reading a keyboard.

https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1

Setting the PWM at 0% with an analogWrite() would cut the sound.